# jQuery UI Accordion Scrolls Page up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm sure there is something posted out there that explains what is happening and how to fix it, but I'm not finding it, so please cut me some slack. If you scroll down below the accordion some, then click an accordion heading, once it opens the page jumps or scrolls up. I don't want it to do this and I've compared it to the UI demo and not sure where I'm going wrong. Help, please!

http://jsfiddle.net/BBvJ4/

```
$(function() {

  $("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true
  });

});

<div id="accordion">

  <h4 id="accordion-header-1"><a href="#">Accoridon Heading</a></h4>
  <div>
    <p>Erat fiant veniam mirum parum. Dolor nihil nihil claram sollemnes notare. Ut parum quam ipsum lius ut. Ullamcorper typi claritate tation nostrud wisi assum. Clari sit laoreet qui augue consuetudium. Lorem me demonstraverunt qui exerci qui. facilisi iriure nobis processus qui. Habent ut quinta ex dolore diam. Lectores tation claram congue eodem quod. Clari sit laoreet qui augue consuetudium. Lorem me qui exerci qui. Luptatum facilisi nobis . Habent ut quinta ex dolore diam. Lectores tation claram congue eodem quod.</p>
  </div>

  <h4 id="accordion-header-2"><a href="#">Accoridon Heading</a></h4>
  <div>
    <p>Erat fiant veniam mirum parum. Dolor nihil nihil claram sollemnes notare. Ut parum quam ipsum lius ut. Ullamcorper typi claritate tation nostrud wisi assum. Clari sit laoreet qui augue consuetudium. Lorem me demonstraverunt qui exerci qui. facilisi iriure nobis processus qui. Habent ut quinta ex dolore diam. Lectores tation claram congue eodem quod. Clari sit laoreet qui augue consuetudium. Lorem me qui exerci qui. Luptatum facilisi nobis . Habent ut quinta ex dolore diam. Lectores tation claram congue eodem quod.</p>
  </div>

  <h4 id="accordion-header-3"><a href="#">Accoridon Heading</a></h4>
  <div>
    <p>Erat fiant veniam mirum parum. Dolor nihil nihil claram sollemnes notare. Ut parum quam ipsum lius ut. Ullamcorper typi claritate tation nostrud wisi assum. Clari sit laoreet qui augue consuetudium. Lorem me demonstraverunt qui exerci qui. facilisi iriure nobis processus qui. Habent ut quinta ex dolore diam. Lectores tation claram congue eodem quod. Clari sit laoreet qui augue consuetudium. Lorem me qui exerci qui. Luptatum facilisi nobis . Habent ut quinta ex dolore diam. Lectores tation claram congue eodem quod.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- end #accordion -->

<div id="dummy"></div>

#accordion {
  display: inline;
  width: 71.138211%;
  /* 700px (div width) / 984px (container width) */ }
  #accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dbd5d1;
    color: #363535;
    font-size: 1em; }
  #accordion h4 {
    background-image: url(../images/accordion-plus.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 11px 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1em;
    /* 16px (from comp) / 16px (browser default size) */
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 8px 0 41px; }
    #accordion h4#accordion-header-1 {
      background-color: #474747; }
    #accordion h4#accordion-header-2 {
      background-color: #7b7979; }
    #accordion h4#accordion-header-3 {
      background-color: #000000; }
    #accordion h4.ui-state-active {
      background-image: url(../images/accordion-minus.png); }
    #accordion h4 a:link, #accordion h4 a:visited {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: 300; }
    #accordion h4 a:hover, #accordion h4 a:focus {
      text-decoration: none; }
  #accordion p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px 25px 39px; }

#dummy { height: 500px; width: 100px; }
```